# Math and physics, where to start?

Tags: mathematics, physics

the only math I know how is to add the velocity to position. Thats it. i would like to know how to do more stuff, physics, collision detection with stuff other than perfect circles, etc.
But where ever I go online to find source to learn I always end up with something that assumes prior knowledge, which is understandable in a lot of cases. But I don't know where to go to learn math and physics from the absolute beginnings. Also I'm dyslexic, so sites or ressources with just definitions of concepts and no relatable examples wont help that much. So could someone give me some links to books and/or sites that can help me learn math and physics for game development.

Comment: There are tons of books. Game Physics Engine Development (The Morgan Kaufmann Series). Physics for Game Developers
(By David M Bourg). And so many more. Also noteworthy what could help :3D Math Primer for Graphics and Game Development. And ofcourse Trigonometry :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry. ( Dyslexia is a difficult thing to bear with, but reading is probably your salvation)

Comment: "how is to add the velocity to position" is known as Euler integration, and is not the only method of doing physics simulation. I have often found that I developed a technique without knowing its official name. Official names of techniques are helpful as you can look them up in reference.

Answer (score 5):

I would typically say this question is off topic, since where to get started is different for everyone. But I think [Khan academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics) is a resource that accommodates a wide range of skill levels. It'll teach you physics and any math you need to get into physics. You can start at whatever level you're comfortable with from basic addition to calculus. The videos are well done, easy to follow and enjoyable to watch.

Answer (score 4):

There's some good resources for learning Maths here on the BBC site, has a range of level such as GCSE (secondary), A-Level (high school?) and university level.

[BBC maths resources](http://www.bbc.co.uk/learning/subjects/maths.shtml)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to watch some [MIT lectures](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/). You can start at the smallest course numbers and work your way up for the first few classes in the physics and math departments.

Answer (score 3):

This year I've been trying to learn more maths for use in making game and the method that has been working for me is to first watch as much Khan Academy as your brain will allow, especially around the area of linear algebra. 
Then grab this book: [Essential Mathematics for Games and Interactive Applications: A Programmer's Guide](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Essential-Mathematics-Games-Interactive-Applications/dp/0123742978/)

And again do as much as your brain will allow, I spent a weekend solid working on the book and followed it up with a few hours here and there in coffee shops but then my brain was full.

As soon as it is full, make some games. They don't have to be complicated, or even work well enough to give to ANYONE but just start coding something and you will soon have some moments where you go. "Hmmm... I could use dot product here" or "Why aren't I doing this with a matrix?" and at that point you have won!

Honestly games (for a hobby at least) should be fun for the person making them as well as for the person who will play it. Don't worry too much if you get stuck on the maths for a time (I haven't picked the book up in a month now but I have been coding loads and using what I have read). You will find that after a while you are running into situations you don't know how to handle more frequently again and you'll naturally drift back to the book and study some more. I've been finding this style very low pressure and very rewarding.

As for the dyslexia, that makes things a little trickier. I have obviously suggested the book that has worked for me but in an environment where books cost so much I'd suggest getting a selection of them through more nefarious means, finding which one suit your learning style, buying that one and deleting the rest. I know its not great to steal books, even temporarily, but no library will stock a decent selection of these kind of books and it really sucks to hand over lots of cash for a book that you find you can't learn from.

Wow that was much longer than I thought it would be, best of luck on your hunt!